# How to save the contents of an array that's in an Alamofire response block?

Tags: arrays, swift, immutability

I have the following code, and I'm trying to save the contents of shops, but the function keeps returning an empty array. Does anyone know why?

```swift
func getAllShops(endPoint: String) -> [Shop]{
    var finalResult:[Shop] = []
    AF.request(self.url + endPoint, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil, interceptor: nil, requestModifier: nil).response {
        (responseData) in
        guard let data = responseData.data else {return}
        
        do{
        let shops = try JSONDecoder().decode([Shop].self, from: data)
            finalResult = shops
            
        } catch {
            print("decoding error: \(error)")
        }
        
    }
    print(finalResult)
    return finalResult
}
```

Comment: The duplicate s about `NSURLSession` but the issue is exactly the same.

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot.